# Change android target version with eclipse

Tags: android, sdk

I was working on android 4.2 (API 17), but I am testing with a device in Android 4.1 (API 16). So I changed The minSdkVersion et the target sdk by going right clicking on the project then  selecting properties > Android and changed the Target Name to Android 4.1. 
After that I changed the two lines in my manifest file :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

But after that I built my project (Project > Clean) and restarted Eclipse, I got errors in my projects that tells me that the R file cannot be resolved to a variable, that I didn't have before.

Is it because I changed the manifest file ? Anybody has an idea how to fix this ? 
Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Delete the `R.java` in generate folder and build again.

Comment: Double-check the files with the error to see if Eclipse added `import android.R;` for you.

Comment: Thanks, after deleting the R.java et rebuilting it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was resolved by upgrading the ADT plugin (Eclipse > Help > Install New Software).  After the upgrade/restart and obligatory Project > Clean, I re-built the library projects successfully.